# Parse different JSON with Decodable (Nested array)

Tags: json, swift4, decodable

I'm working on an app from NiceHash api. The JSON I have to work with looks like this:

```
 {
    "result":{
        "addr":"37ezr3FDDbPXWrCSKNfWzcxXZnc7qHiasj",
        "workers":[
                    [ "worker1", { "a":"45.7" }, 9, 1, "32", 0, 14 ],
                    [ "worker1", { }, 5, 1, "100000", 0, 22 ],
        ]
        "algo":-1
    },
    "method":"stats.provider.workers"
}
```

for parsing made such structures

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    var result: WorkersResult?
    var method: String?
}

struct WorkersResult: Decodable {
    var addr: String?
    var workers: [Workers]?
    var algo: Int?
}

struct Workers: Decodable {
    var worker: [Worker]?
}

struct Worker: Decodable {
    var name: String?
    var hashrate: Hashrate?
    var time: Int?
    var XNSUB: Int?
    var difficult: String?
    var reject: Int?
    var algo: Int?
}

struct Hashrate: Decodable {
    var rate: String?
}
```

response is equal nil, I can not understand what I'm doing wrong, I understand that the problem is parsing arrays of workers, since if  I commented workers the response equal some valid data. 
Thanks for help!

Comment: Is there a reason that all your properties are optionals? For example, can any of them be missing from the JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You JSON is actually invalid due to the misplaced comma. Run it through a JSON validator to now what I mean.

Anyhow, since `Worker` (singular) is encoded as an array, you need to provide a custom decoder for it. `Workers` (plural) is unnecessary.

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    var result: WorkersResult?
    var method: String?
}

struct WorkersResult: Decodable {
    var addr: String?
    var workers: [Worker]?
    var algo: Int?
}

struct Worker: Decodable {
    var name: String?
    var hashrate: Hashrate?
    var time: Int?
    var XNSUB: Int?
    var difficult: String?
    var reject: Int?
    var algo: Int?

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        name      = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self)
        hashrate  = try container.decodeIfPresent(Hashrate.self)
        time      = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self)
        XNSUB     = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self)
        difficult = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self)
        reject    = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self)
        algo      = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self)
    }
}

struct Hashrate: Decodable {
    var rate: String?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case rate = "a"
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let jsonData = """
{
    "result":{
        "addr":"37ezr3FDDbPXWrCSKNfWzcxXZnc7qHiasj",
        "workers":[
                    [ "worker1", { "a":"45.7" }, 9, 1, "32", 0, 14 ],
                    [ "worker1", { }, 5, 1, "100000", 0, 22 ]
        ],
        "algo":-1
    },
    "method":"stats.provider.workers"
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let r = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: jsonData)
print(r)
```